# Python target the element before a given element in a list

Tags: python, list, dictionary

I have a dictionary:

```
d = {'a': ['Thing', 'City', 10], 'b': ['Thing' ,'City', 5]}
```

and so on and `num = 10`

I want to go through the dictionary and check to see if num matches up with any of the other numbers in the lists of the dictionary. If so, I want to grab the 2 elements before the number and return all 3.

So for example, in this case, since `num = 10` and `a` has a `10`, it should return `['Thing', 'City' 10]`.

So far I have this:

```
for i in d.keys(): # goes through the dictionary
    for item in d[i]:
        if type(item) == int: # if the item is an int
            if num = item:
                 l.append(item)
                 #l.append the items before it
```

I guess my question then boils down to this: How do I get the items before a given element in the list? So in this case I have the 10 but also want the Thing and City.

Thank You!

Answer (score 2):

Try something like this:

```
for key, item in d.items():
  for idx, subitem in enumerate(item):
    if isinstance(subitem, int) and subitem == num:
      l.extend(subitem[idx-2:idx+1])
```

Answer (score 2):

Use the `in` keyword to simply things.

```
def get_list(num, d):
    for lst in d.values(): 
        if num in lst:
            return(lst) #or do whatever you want with the list
```

Example:

```
d = {'a': ['Thing', 'City', 10], 'b': ['Thing' ,'City', 5]}
get_list(10, d)
>>>  ['Thing', 'City', 10]
get_list(5,d)
>>>  ['Thing', 'City', 5]
```

Comment: Sorry, I don't just want the list to return, I want to access the element before the number, so something like lst[num-1] or something (although that doesn't work)

Answer (score 0):

If simply the last element of `d`'s value is to be compared, and there could be multiple occurrences... (this doesn't do an implicit type check though)...

```
matching = [k for k,v in d.iteritems() if v[-1] == 10]
for k in matching:
    print k, d[k]
```

Answer (score 0):

```
result = [v for v in d.itervalues() if v[2] == num]
```